# Joining 3 SQL queries into one result set

Tags: sql, join

here are the 3 queries the important thing is all three queries are based on date range and need to match up qry 1 assestnumber with snissued and snredeemed. thanks in advance

```
select 
    assetnumber, sum(mocalc),sum(micalc), sum(cocalc),sum(cicalc)
from 
    drops
where  
    dropdate > '09/01/2012' 
    and dropdate < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate())
group by 
    assetnumber

select 
    snissued,sum(amount) 
from 
    tickets
where  
    dateissued > '09/01/2012' 
    and dateissued < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate())
group by 
    snissued

select 
    snredeemed,sum(amount) 
from 
    tickets
where  
    dateredeemed > '09/01/2012' 
    and dateredeemed < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate())
group by 
    snredeemed
```

in the first i am summing the 4 fileds i am using and grouping by the assetnumber for specified date range

2nd i am pulling from another table sum of amounts for snissued for date range
3rd  i am pulling from another table sum of amounts for snredeemed fore date range

for the output i want the first table then 2 more colums snissued(sum amounts) and snredeemed (sum amounts)

here is the current output

```
qry 1
0-2459-36182    843 869 14  40
0-2621-31924    64700   86900   3000    25200
0-2739-41401    5702    5738    204 236
```

qry 2

```
0-2459-36182    162800
0-2621-31924    145000
0-2739-41401    298200
```

qry 3

```
0-2459-36182    157200
0-2621-31924    157800
0-2739-41401    292800
```

this is result i want

```
0-2459-36182    843     869     14      40     162800  157200  
0-2621-31924    64700   86900   3000    25200  145000  157800
0-2739-41401    5702    5738    204     236    298200  292800
```

Comment: Did you try UNION operator ? Please add the errors you are facing along with the SQL command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather you aren't looking for UNION as others ahve suggested, but need the 3 rows to have 2 additional columns showing snissued and snredeemed per assetnumber. Is that correct?
If so do a left join on all 3 similar to this:

```
select DRPS.assetnumber, DRPS.MOCALCSUM,DRPS.MICALCSUM,
    DRPS.COCALCSUM,DRPS.CICALCSUM,ISSUED.TotalIssued,REDEEMED.TotalRedeemed
from (select assetnumber, sum(mocalc) AS [MOCALCSUM],sum(micalc) AS [MICALCSUM],
        sum(cocalc) AS [COCALCSUM],sum(cicalc) AS [CICALCSUM]
        from drops
        where  dropdate > '09/01/2012' and dropdate < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate())
        group by assetnumber) AS DRPS
LEFT JOIN (select snissued,sum(amount) AS [TotalIssued] from tickets
    where  dateissued > '09/01/2012' and dateissued < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate())
    group by snissued) AS ISSUED
    ON DRPS.assetnumber=ISSUED.snissued
LEFT JOIN (select snredeemed,sum(amount) AS [TotalRedeemed] from tickets
    where  dateredeemed > '09/01/2012' and dateredeemed < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate())
    group by snredeemed) AS REDEEMED
    ON DRPS.assetnumber=REDEEMED.snredeemed
```

Hope that's right! Post any errors and I'll correct.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'snissued'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'MOCALCSCUM'.

Comment: to be clearyes 3 row have to have 2 additonal columns the additional colum is a sum of the amount column for a serial number snissued or snredeemed. snissued

Comment: ok i fixed the 2 errors first error should have been snredeemed not snissued and 2nd error removed C from SCUM. so far working in sql will add to my code and test again thanks so much

Comment: Also meant to add: If you want to ensure you get a numeric result even if there are no matching amounts for snissued and snredeemed against a given assetnumber you should replace ISSUED.TotalIssued and REDEEMED.TotalRedeemed in the top SELECT with ISNULL(ISSUED.TotalIssued,0) and ISNULL(REDEEMED.TotalRedeemed,0)

Comment: hmm maybe that why every once in a while i get an error, but in the tickets table there should never be an entry without an amount or a snissued number but the snredeemed filed can be null. what happens is when a ticket is issued the the tickets table is populated with ticket number, snissued(serial number of device issueing ticket) amount of ticket, and dateissued (date ticket issued). when i ticket is redeemed which can be dyas later or on a different machine then the row with ticket number is updated with the snredeemed and dateredeemed. i will try and see what is cuasing the error on null

Comment: The ISNULL in the root SELECT would only ensure you get a numeric value for the TotalIssued and TotalRedeemed columns. I'm not sure I followed your most recent comment, but if it's possible to have NULL in the Tickets.amount field then try SUM(ISNULL(amount,0)). What error are you getting? Is it still within this query or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    q1.*, snissuedsum, snredeemedsum
from
(
    select assetnumber, sum(mocalc) q11,sum(micalc) q12, sum(cocalc) q13,sum(cicalc) q14
    from drops 
    where  dropdate > '09/01/2012' 
    and dropdate < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate()) 
    group by assetnumber 
) q1
left join
(
    select snissued,sum(amount) snissuedsum 
    from tickets 
    where  dateissued > '09/01/2012' 
    and dateissued < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate()) 
    group by snissued 
) q2
  on q1.assetnumber = q2.snissued
  left join
(     
    select snredeemed,sum(amount) snredeemedsum
    from tickets 
    where  dateredeemed > '09/01/2012' 
    and dateredeemed < dateadd(hour,-0,getdate()) 
    group by snredeemed 
) q3
  on q1.assetnumber = q3.snredeemed
```

Comment: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
The column 'snissued' was specified multiple times for 'q2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'assetnumber'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
The column 'snredeemed' was specified multiple times for 'q3'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'assetnumber'.

Comment: Ah, yes - wasn't paying attention to your column names. See edit